# testing network transfer speed and hardware limitations

Tags: networking, hardware, software-rec, benchmark, infiniband

This is somewhat of a computer engineering and network engineering question, but it is linux based since *infiband* is largely utilized via the linux operating system.  And I am interested in understanding the speed limits that would happen while using the linux operating system on my hardware.

*Infiniband* (mellanox) has had many data rate releases: QDR, FRD, EDR, HDR.

Currently HDR is at either 100 gbps or 200 gbps (see mellanox advertising as of 2021).

In using `iperf` under `rhel 7.9` via **IPoIB** iperf reported a maximum transfer speed of 24.0 gbps (over TCP I believe).  On a 100 gbps that is 24%, versus a reported 942 mbps on a 1gbps network which is 94%.

My question is: as infinband goes from HDR to a future NDR and XDR and whatever those gbps may be  can someone report on or calculate where the choke point could possibly be?  For example i did and SSH `scp` test and ssh cipher choice mattered resulting in either a 1.600 hbps to a maximum of 5.6 gbps  (200 MB/s or 700 MB/s) transfer speed which I believe was the limitation of the cpu's ability to process and do the chosen encryption scheme.

What are numbers regarding  cpu / DDR4 ram / chipset / PCIe lane limitations in relation to a 100gbps inifiband network speed?

How fast can the current Intel or AMD [chipsets?] with LGA1200 or LGA3647 and with PCIe 3.0 sling bits to a mellanox infiniband card?

And how in linux [RHEL 7.9] can I test this sort of thing, is iperf the *best* way?

Comment: How wide is your card's PCI? PCI 3.0 x16 can do 126gbps. As the card is doing CPU offload, I don't think you're limited by CPU/ram. https://www.mellanox.com/sites/default/files/doc-2020/pb-connectx-4-en-ic.pdf

Answer (score 1):

InfiniBand (at least the Mellanox hardware) uses CPU offloading and can achieve very high throughput without significant CPU load. The raw speed can be well tested using the InfiniBand verbs performance tests in the [perftest](https://github.com/linux-rdma/perftest) package, e.g. `ib_write_bw`. The measured data rate is usually >95 % of the specified connection rate.

The iperf tool uses by default a single TCP connection, which is the primary bottleneck here. TCP connections are CPU-intensive, and a single TCP connection cannot saturate the fast InfiniBand connection. Using several TCP connections in parallel (`-P` option to `iperf`), one can come closer to the InfiniBand network data rate on a multicore machine. But in general, due to their substantial overhead, TCP connections are not ideally suited for fast networks.